# Unable to Deploy Spring Boot Application in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, corretto

I've seen this question asked on this site throughout the years, but none of the solutions have worked for me. I'm attempting to launch a spring boot application using AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I am getting the "502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.20.0" error that many others have gotten. Looking at my logs it says "connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.16.189, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5000/"".

In my code I have specified the app to use port 5000:
[image]

I've also specified it within the environment properties:

[image]

I'm at a loss as to why I'm still receiving this error, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the port really a part of the problem? Eg can you change it and leave it on your default port? Does it work?

Comment: Leaving it as the default (8080) gives me the same error. From what I've read, it seems to be an issue with talking to the port in AWS. The quick answer should be to just swap it to 5000 which is what nginx uses, but that's still not working. I'm thinking it could be an issue with the security groups as well but I'm unsure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other considerations when deploying an AWS Spring BOOT app. Are you using an AWS Service Client in your app. If so, how are you setting the creds? How did you package your app? Did you package all the dependencies.

Follow this small example and see if you can get this app deployed.

[Creating your first AWS Java web application](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_first_project)

This app is successfully deployed:

[image]

Comment: This is going to be a stupid question, so I apologize in advance. Would my jdk be causing this issue? I'm using jdk14.0.1. I figured that wouldn't be the reason I'm getting a connection refused exception though.

Comment: Very possible -- try following this with 1.8

Comment: Ended up using the Amazon Corretto JDK and that seems to have done the trick. Still not sure why this fixed it but at least it's working now.